# Channel ID Comparisons in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get the bot to reply to a message that was edited, but only in a specific channel. It seems to just disregard my comparison of SelectedChannel and the after message channel ID. Is there an error in how I am getting the channel ID?

```
selectedChannel = (channel id here)

@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if (before.content != after.content) and (selectedChannel == after.channel.id):
        await after.reply("Edit")
```

Comment: *"seems to jus disregard my comparison"* - Disregard how? It posts the message in any channel that an edit takes place, or none at all? Have you made sure that the channel id is the correct one? And have you made sure you've restarted the bot since you made any changes?

Comment: In all channels regardless of ID.

Comment: The code works flawlessly for me. Make sure that 1. `selectedChannel` is an integer, and 2. The message is loaded in the internal cache (you can do this by sending a random message *when* the bot is online, otherwise use the `on_raw_message_edit`)

Comment: So weird. I tried that code again, and it worked flawlessly.